# Is there any official ports of Ubuntu touch for nexus 6

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there any official ports of Ubuntu touch for nexus 6?
I searched the whole internet and not seems to find anything juicy.
I remember it used to support in my old galaxy nexus and nexus 7.

Comment: In case you want to get this working: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/

Comment: I'll close this for now to the master question - when/if nexus 6 is supported should go into the master question.

Comment: In fact I am going through that now, It says "You can find all the needed Android specific git repositories at https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com. This is a working gerrit server with everything needed to build the Android images used by Ubuntu Touch. The reference tree in there is based on AOSP (4.4.2 specifically), so make sure your device specific repositories are compatible with AOSP at least." But there is no 4.4.2 version branch for Nexus 6. so I think it will be difficult for porting it

Comment: You can vote for a port here with $$ => https://devices.ubports.com/#/shamu (Nexus 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Nexus 6 is not officially supported. A rundown of possible devices does not list any Nexus 6:

[List of supported devices](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/):

- Nexus 4
- Nexus 7 2013 WiFi
- Nexus 10

No longer supported but had community support:

- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus 7 2012

[Not supported but port with system-image server or work in progress](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) also does not list a Nexus 6.

Answer (score 0):

No.As far as I have skimmed there is no Nexus 6 custom rom.However a new porting guide was released so it is not impossible that an image appears.